# JDK in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, java

I found two JDK in my Mac,
one is in the path:'`/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0jdk`'
another is in the path:'`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0jdk`'

what's the different? why there are two?

Answer (score 4):

The `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0jdk` is the JDK that Apple used to distribute with their operating system. They have since stopped providing a JDK and have left it up to the owner of the Java platform, Oracle, to provide the latest JDK and `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0jdk` is the JDK provided by Oracle.

The difference is simply the version and vendor (provider) of the JDK. It's perfectly fine to have multiple JDKs on your system.